# How to lock exposure in camerax?

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camerax

There is `setAutoExposureLock()` method in the old camera api.

And also it is possible to lock the exposure like this in camera2:

```
builder.set(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_LOCK, true);
```

How to do this in CameraX? Right now I'm using `ImageCapture.Builder` to take a picture.  Quick internet search didn't give me the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for the `Camera2InterOp` API. https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/camera2/interop/Camera2Interop

```
ImageCapture.Builder builder = new ImageCapture.Builder();
Camera2Interop.Extender<ImageCapture> extender = new Camera2Interop.Extender<>(builder);
extender.setCaptureRequestOption(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_LOCK, true);
```